# pacman/yaourt/Arch Linux: How to get CLI summary of out-of-date packages

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

How can I get an update summary from `pacman` showing up in the command line?
It should simply tell me how many packages are out of date, maybe with a few options of sorting (e.g. only kernel/`core` packages)
I know that `octopi` gets exactly what I want, but it displays it in the tray, while I want it to be accessible from the command line.

Comment: `checkupdates --help`

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks for the clarification why `pacman -Sy` is terrible advice. It is interesting to note, though, that the `man` page of `pacman`, states: "[pacman -Qu] works best if the sync database is refreshed using -Sy".

Comment: @pfnuesel That's *almost* a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pacman ships with a utility *specifically* for this use case: `checkupdates`:

> checkupdates --help
>   checkupdates (pacman) v5.0.2
>
> Safely print a list of pending updates

This ensures that you are not misguidedly running `Pacman -Sy` to update your local database without simulataneously upgrading any out-of-date packages, thereby (inadvertently) running an unsupported [partial upgrade](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported).

To print the results of `checkupdates` to your terminal or statusbar/conky/whatever, you just query the temporary database:

```
pacman -Qqu --dbpath /tmp/checkup-db-user/
```

You can then set up a systemd-timer or cron job to refresh this database without worrying that you will break your system.

pacman ships with a variety of helpful utilities, you can see them all with:

```
 pacman -Ql pacman | awk -F/ '/bin/ {print $4}'
```